# Are graph databases better suited to store trees than key-val stores?

Tags: graph, nosql, neo4j, scalability, graph-databases

My application data consists of a huge tree that grows as users interact with the system. Are graph databases more suited to store big trees than key-val stores? Is the loss in scalability (for the fact graph dbs are usually harder to shard) compensated by other features?

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned Document databases like Mongo DB. Or maybe that's just a type of key-value store? In my experience document databases are not the answer to storing trees because you cannot access internal nodes without reading the entire document tree into memory. I hope one day someone comes up with a NoSQL tree database.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

If you use a key value store, I would imagine you would do a lot of lookups for the children, and this could be a long list, so your key would be the parent node, and your value the children, and you could end up with a lot of movement and querying of the table. This is typically the problem you have in Relational Databases, these type of table joins.

A Graph Database is great as you do not do joins, but traversals, so you would start at the root, and specify depth, or an end condition, then you could let the graph traversal use outgoing relationships to get you to your end result.

I agree with you that sharding is not a good option for Graph Databases, at least not in the sense of cross-store relationship traversals. But I believe with proper modeling of your data, this shouldn't be a problem, at least not if the Graph Database is smart.

Neo4j has a problem with dense nodes, where a node with many(500k+) relationships can cause a slow down on traversals, but you can use indexing the get around this problem. Aside from this, it's great for large data as it's storage on disk is efficient, and it's traversals are very fast.

Comment: @Viclib Maybe taking a look at Titan would help instead of Neo4J. It focuses on sharding using a backend storage like HBase or Cassandra.

Comment: Yes, that would be an alternative, though I'm only versed in Neo4j. Does Titan do it's node/relationship connections through key/value pairing?

Comment: Never used it either. I do know nodes are basically sets of K/V, but not sure about relationships. It seems to be the case when looking at the docs : https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Property-Graph-Model "each edge has a collection of properties defined by a map from key to value."

Answer (score 1):

Define "huge".  If you can fit within the confines/limitations of Neo4J or have a natural and logical sharding model, Neo4J would be a much cleaner/simpler/more powerful approach and would require a lot less code.  As Nicholas said, if your database will have a lot of "hot spot" nodes (many relationships), you might have some challenges w/Neo4J, though there are generally application design approaches you can use to work around that limitation.